# Вывести блок поверх другого блока если первый блок внутри второго

Tags: html, css, height

Добрый день! Возник вопрос в ходе работы. Есть два блока, к примеру: `<div class="first">`(`height:100px`) и дочерний ему блок `<div class="second">`(`height:50px`). Мне необходимо `<div class="second">` вынести за пределы родителя, чтобы этот дочерний блок был видим без увеличения высоты родителя. Или вопрос по другому: в родителе и в дочернем блоке есть тексты - там и там, мне необходимо в родителе вывести только 3 строки, а дочернем блоке вывести одну строку ниже высоты родителя.

```html
<html>
  <head>
  <style>
    .first{
      height: 100px;
    }
    .second{
      height: 50px;
    }
    .main{
      height:1000px;
      width:1000px;
    }
  </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="main">
      <div class="first">
        какой-то очень большой текст
      <div class="second">
        еще один текст
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Мне нужно как-то `.second` вывести на уровень `.main` за пределы `.first`.

Comment: Перефразируйте вопрос - ничего не понятно

Comment: сейчас кодом отображу

Comment: Добавьте код в вопрос и уточните на каком языке вам нужно это сделать

Comment: css, на крайний случай (самый крайний) js

Comment: добавил код в сообщении

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
  <head>
  <style>
    .first{
      height: 100px;
      position:relative;
      border-bottom:1px solid black;
    }
    .second{
      height: 50px;
      position:absolute;
      top:100%;
    }
    .main{
      height:1000px;
      width:1000px;
    }
  </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="main">
      <div class="first">
        какой-то очень большой текст
      <div class="second">
        еще один текст
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Если правильно понял, то примерно так - нижний бордюр у родителя что бы видеть его высоту. Для second можно еще добавить z-index > 0